# EntityTag table not available to drupal view

Tags: drupal-views

Creating a view in drupal, when I try to add a field I see all the normal civiCRM fields for contacts, email, etc, but what I want is the entity_tag table for the contact id which does not appear in the list of available fields.

The table is listed in sites/default/settings.php, but it is not available in the view

Comment: are you sure you can't get what you need just by looking for the 'tag' field

Comment: There is no tag field, or any field with "tag" in it

Comment: What are you basing your View on? CiviContact?

Answer (score -1):

I created a view based on civicontact and it seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your post.  Could you edit your answer to provide a bit more detail?  This might help other people who are in the same situation.